# Using ROW_NUMBER() to Partition DataSets

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, window-functions

I'm a bit confused on using `ROW_NUMBER()` in SQL.

have a dataset that currently looks as follows:

```
 Number ID
    1   1
    2   6
    3   11
```

I have written a query below:

```
SELECT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Number), Number
FROM #SEQNUMBERSTEMP
```

Which is giving the output:

```
rownum  Number
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
1       5
1       6
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
1       1
```

But I want to achieve the following:

```
rownum  Number
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
1       5
2       1    # Note 2 should start at position 6
2       2
2       3
2       4
2       5
3       1    # Note 3 should start at position 11
3       2
3       3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use `DENSE_RANK()` without a `PARTITION BY` clause, like :

```
SELECT rownum = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Number), Number
FROM #SEQNUMBERSTEMP
```

Comment: I am late by 13 seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

use rank()

```
SELECT
            rownum = rank() OVER (ORDER BY Number),
            Number
        FROM #SEQNUMBERSTEMP
```

Comment: rank() is giving me same result set